# Shortening a list of global variables that start with the same value

Tags: javascript

In my code I have a long list of global variables which all start off with the same value but change independently. Instead of using up 30 lines defining them, is there a way to define them together? (Specifically all the y values)

```
var cx1 = 0,
    cx2 = 100,
    cx3 = 200,
    cx4 = 300,
    cx5 = 400,
    cx6 = 500,
    cx7 = 600,
    cx8 = 700,
    cx9 = 800,
    cx10 = 900,
    cy = 100,
    y1 = 315,
    y2 = 685,
    y12 = 315,
    y22 = 685,
    y13 = 315,
    y23 = 685,
    y14 = 315,
    y24 = 684,
    y15 = 315,
    y25 = 685,
    y16 = 315,
    y26 = 685,
    y17 = 315,
    y27 = 685,
    y18 = 315,
    y28 = 685,
    y19 = 315,
    y29 = 685,
    y110 = 315,
    y220 = 685,
    endx,
    endy;
```

Comment: The answer is yes, but no! Use arrays. Dont waste the scope.

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks :D

Comment: So if i have say `var y = new Array("315", "685")`, how do I recall those later? Or do I change the `'y'` and it with altar the array accordingly?

Comment: all most all values are random. there is no relation amongst them. `y24 = 684` which is a odd one.

Comment: `y24 = 684` is a typo, but all the `y1's` are 315, and all the y2's are 685...

Comment: why not just do two variables than?

Comment: @coopercape thats sth you should have mentioned in your question...

Comment: They all are changed by different values within different functions just need the same starting point... also thought it would be obvious that they were the same... probably because I already knew, apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of thousands of variables may use *one* array:

```
var y = [undefined, 315, 685,/*...*/];
```

Or if repeating:

```
var y=",315,685".repeat(10).split(",").slice(1);
```

And then access:

```
y[1]; //instead of y1
```

Or alternatively use an object ( if there are more spaces in the array than values):

```
var y = {
1:315,
 2:685,
 12:315,
 22:685,
 13:315,
 23:685,
 14:315,
 24:684,
 15:315,
 25:685,
 16:315,
 26:685,
 17:315,
 27:685,
 18:315,
 28:685,
 19:315,
 29:685,
 110:315,
 220:685
};
```

If you really really want to do it the wrong way, take the upper object/array and copy it into window:

```
Object.keys(y)/* or just y for the array way*/.forEach(function(key){
   window["y"+key]=y[key];
});

alert(y1);
```

Comment: Think I'll just go with the array... looks pretty neat and easy to access the variables... thanks :p

Comment: @coopercape also have a look at t.j. crowders answer if the values are really repeating. He has so many rep for a reason ;)... And youre welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

> (Specifically all the y values)

Since the even y values are all 315 and the odd ones are all 685, you could build yourself an array of them:

```js
var y = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 28; ++i) {
    y[i] = i % 2 === 0 ? 315 : 685;
}
// Then you refer to them by index
console.log(y[0]); // 315
y[0] = 320;
console.log(y[0]); // 320
```

If it's important that you be able to refer to the `y` values with the odd series of numbers you're using (15, 25, 110, etc.), you could make them object properties:

```js
var y = Object.create(null);
[1, 2, 12, 22, 23, 14, 24, 15, 25, 16, 26, 17, 27, 18, 28, 19, 29, 110, 220].forEach(function(value, index) {
    y[value] = index % 2 === 0 ? 315 : 685;
});
console.log(y[22]); // 685
y[22] = 670;
console.log(y[22]); // 670
```

In ES2015+, you might use a `Map` instead:

```js
const y = new Map();
[1, 2, 12, 22, 23, 14, 24, 15, 25, 16, 26, 17, 27, 18, 28, 19, 29, 110, 220].forEach((value, index) => {
    y.set(value, index % 2 === 0 ? 315 : 685);
});
console.log(y.get(22)); // 685
y.set(22, 670);
console.log(y.get(22)); // 670
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and objects.

```
cx = [0,100,200,300];
cy = [100];
y = {
  1: 315,
  2: 685,
  110: 315
}
// etc.

//to use
cx[0] == 0
cx[1] == 100
y['1'] == 315
y['110'] == 315
```

Answer (score 0):

May be till this can be accomplished. after that we have add some logic for cleaning out `0`.

```js
var vals = [315, 685];
var arr = {};
for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= vals.length; i++) {
    var key = (j % 10 == 0) ? i : '' + i + j;
    arr['y' + key] = vals[i - 1];
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```